# Stored Procedure not being created

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have written a simple query to run a stored procedure in MySQL to update the zip code of an address but its saying that there's an error in the syntax.

I have set the delimiter to // but still its giving a syntax error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Update_Zip (IN ZIP1 INT, IN addr varchar(50))  
BEGIN
UPDATE Address
SET zip = ZIP1 WHERE street_address = addr;
END//
```

Error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Version: MySQL '8.0.28'

Thank you for the help

Comment: I tested this and it is created with no syntax error. Can you please edit your question and include the exact error message you saw? It should indicate precisely where the syntax failed. Also please include the result of `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: Also name the client you are using to execute this. E.g. mysql command-line client, MySQL Workbench, phpmyadmin, etc.

Comment: I've added the error

Comment: When the syntax error reports `near ''` it means it got to the end of your CREATE PROCEDURE statement but it expected something more. Like if you open a block with `BEGIN` but forget to include a matching `END`, or if you open a parenthesis but don't close it. But I don't see anything like that in your example.

Comment: Looks like a delimiter problem. With a single statement `BEGIN` / `END` [aren't needed](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=09cd5c5dc714853de09cf92c7e73c730).

Comment: If you didn't change the delimiter, then the error `near ''` would be expected, because the parser thinks the first `;` is the end of the CREATE PROCEDURE statement. I suppose you didn't really change the delimiter. Or you changed the delimiter, but then started a new session which resets the delimiter.

Comment: It was a delimiter problem. I removed Begin and End as suggested above and it worked perfectly fine since it was a single statement. Thank you all for your inputs